# Read glob from command line in Bash

Tags: bash, glob

How do I read a glob in Bash from command line? I tried this and it only picks up the first file in the glob:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
FILES=$1
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  echo $f
done
```

Let's say my script is script.sh. I want to call it like `sh script.sh /home/hss/* 4 gz`
(where `/home/hss/*`, `4` and `gz` are the command line arguments). When I try the above script, it reads only the first file. Any ideas?

Comment: The best practice is to take your glob as the **last** argument. `sh script.sh 4 gz /home/hss/*` doesn't require the glob to be quoted; with that calling convention, you can just pop the leading arguments off and then iterate (`num=$1; shift; ext=$1; shift; for file; do echo "processing $file"; done`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote any parameters which contain shell meta-characters when calling the script, to avoid pathname expansion (by your current shell):

```
sh script.sh "/home/hss/*" 4 gz
```

Thus `$1` will be assigned the pattern and not the first matched file.

Comment: True insofar as it goes, but not a good practice. For instance, one couldn't pass `'/home/hss/directory with spaces/*.txt'` as an argument to this program in a way it'll understand.

Answer (score 10):

You need to access all the contents of the parameters that are passed to the script. The glob is expanded by the shell before your script is executed.

You could copy the array:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=("$@")
for f in "${FILES[@]}"
do
    echo "Processing $f file..."
    echo "$f"
done
```

Or iterate directly:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f     # equivalent to for f in "$@"
do
    echo "Processing $f file..."
    echo "$f"
done
```

Or use `shift`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while (($# > 0))
do
    echo "Processing $1 file..."
    echo "$1"
    shift
done
```

Comment: Needs more quotes. `files=( "$@" )`; `for f in "${files[@]}"` -- otherwise, there's no advantage over `${array[*]}` syntax.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it reads only the first file, is that the pattern `/home/hss/*` gets expanded **before** it is passed as an argument to your script. So your script does not see it as a pattern, but as a list of files, matching that glob.

So, you need to call it like eugene y specified in his post:

```
sh script.sh "/home/hss/*" 4 gz
```

The quoting of `$1` looks optional to me. It just makes the pattern to expand in `for` cycle rather than in assignment.