# How to expand 2nd argument if it's a glob pattern?

Tags: bash, glob

I'm trying to write a script that counts the number of matches of some pattern in a list of files and outputs its findings. Essentially I want to call the command like this:

`count-per-file.sh str_needle *.c`

and get output like:

```
Main.c: 12
Foo.c: 1
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Count occurences of pattern in files.
#
# Usage:
#   count-per-file.sh SEARCH_PATTERN GLOB_EXPR
for file in "$2"; do
    count=$(grep -a "$1" "$file" | wc -l)
    if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "$file: $count"
    fi
done
```

The problem is if I call it like so I don't know how to loop over the file list, so this outputs nothing:

```
count-per-file.sh str_needle *.c
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5065321/797744) but it deals the glob pattern being the only argument to the script, whereas in my script the first argument is the search pattern, and the rest are the files expanded from the glob.

Comment: If you call it like `count-per-file.sh str_needle *.c` then the second argument won't be `*.c`; your shell will have expanded it into `Main.c` and `Foo.c` (as the second and *third* argument*s*).

Comment: @Biffen Right, how would I loop over those files if my first argument is always the search_pattern?

Comment: `shift`, then `for file`. You do know that `grep -oc str_needle *.c` does what you want though, right? And that `grep ...|wc -l` won't give you the number of occurrences, but just the number of lines?

Comment: `shift` then `for file in "$@"`

Comment: I'll read up on `shift` thanks. That `grep` command is similar but it lists all files, even if there were no matches, whereas my script lists only files that have had at least one match.

Comment: @MichaelBurr `for file` is enough.

Comment: @NewWorld `grep -oc str_needle *.c|grep -v ':0$'`...? Or in your loop; something like `grep -q "$1" "$file" && grep -oc "$1" "$file"`, or `count=$(grep -oc "$1" "$file")`.

Comment: It worked, thank you :) So if you want to add this as an answer I'll upvote it and edit in my working script.

Comment: @Biffen Didn't think about grepping out `:0$`. Nice one

Comment: If you aren't concerned about the actual count, just whether it is non-zero, consider using `if grep -q -a "$1" "$file"; then` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested I used `shift` which seems to 'pop' the first argument. Here's my working script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Count occurences of pattern in files.
#
# Usage:
#   count-per-file.sh SEARCH_PATTERN GLOB_EXPR
search_pattern="$1"
shift

for file in "$@"; do
    count=$(grep -aiE "$search_pattern" "$file" | wc -l)
    if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "$file: $count"
    fi
done
```

Comment: `shift` doesn't pop; it shifts. To pop is to remove the *last* of a list.

Comment: He's using "pop" informally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring parameter expansion with an start index like this to skip the first n-1 values in `$@`

`"${@:n}"`

e.g.

```
for FILE in "${@:2}" 
do
  echo $FILE
done
```

**N.B.** Your script doesn't get a 'glob pattern' as the second argument. 
The shell that calls your script expands the glob to a space separated list of files *before your script sees it* and passes this to your script as the parameter list. This is why you can use [standard substring range expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_expansion).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```
#!/bin/bash
# Count occurences of pattern in files.
#
# Usage:
#   count-per-file.sh SEARCH_PATTERN GLOB_EXPR
for file in $2; do                               #UNQUOTE THIS TO EXPAND GLOB
    count=$(grep -a "$1" "$file" | wc -l)
    if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "$file: $count"
    fi
done
```

Then pass the glob in in quotes so it doesn't expand on the command line

```
count-per-file.sh str_needle '*.c'
```

Comment: That doesn't work because it just does one iteration of the loop where `$file` is the very first file in the glob expansion.

Comment: Oh it does work, I had to pass the glob argument in quotes, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add the quotes while passing `*.c` and remove quotes while using them in `for` loop and it will work..

```
[root@client1 ~]# cat  count-per-file.sh
#!/bin/bash
# Count occurences of pattern in files.
#
# Usage:
#   count-per-file.sh SEARCH_PATTERN GLOB_EXPR
for file in $2; do
    count=$(grep -a "$1" $file | wc -l)
    if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "$file: $count"
    fi
done
[root@client1 ~]# bash count-per-file.sh str_needle "*.c"
file.c: 1
Main.c: 12
[root@client1 ~]#
```