# How does ls turn off globbing without doing a set -f noglob

Tags: bash, glob

I need for my script this, say if user provides file* I want the asterisk passed to my script instead of globbing. So I tried set -f noglob for my test and that helps in a way but want to know how does ls disable globbing without the need for set -f noglob in bash.
Before doing set -f noglob

```
#./test_asterisk.sh file.*.*
file.20160308.115411

#ls file.*.*
file.20160308.145009
file.20160308.145010
file.20160308.115411:
file.20160308.115420:
file.20160308.115422:
file.20160308.145007:
```

I can get the same result if I do

```
#set -f noglob
```

before running the script.

Comment: What about that makes you think `ls` disabled globbing?

Comment: I may have made some assumption, got it wrong perhaps but point was how ls is immune to it. How could I get the same behavior for my script.

Comment: You can't. By the time the command, script, etc. is run the globbing has **already** been done by the shell that runs the command, script, etc. You can't retroactively prevent it.

Comment: Also I don't believe that example output from `ls`. That's not the output you would get from that command. You would get an error from `ls` about that file not existing. (You would get that output from `ls -1 file.*.*` though.)

Comment: Thanks Etan, corrected a paste error in the output snippet. Some related thread that showed up sort of answers this [Read glob from command line bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063864/read-glob-from-command-line-bash?rq=1)

Comment: I have no idea what `test_asterisk.sh` is doing but it looks like it is doing `echo $3` or the rough equivalent since it gets the globbed files as positional arguments.

Comment: And that other question says the same thing this does. Once your script is running the glob is *already* expanded and you can operate on all the globbed files but that's it.

Comment: Yeah, the test_asterisk.sh just does `snapdelete=$1` `for f in "$snapdelete" do echo $f done`

Comment: Not with that output from `ls` it doesn't but ok. And `for f in "$var"` is pointless, it will never run the loop more than once.

Answer (score 4):

Glob expansion or [*Filename expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) is a feature of the shell, not a feature of ls. Because of that it can get disabled only by the shell.